# If {$v_1, v_2,..., v_k$} is a linearly independent set of vectors, then so is {$L(v_1), L(v_2),..., L(v_k)$}?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

**Prove or disprove:**

If {$v_1, v_2,..., v_k$} is a linearly independent set of vectors, then so is
{$L(v_1), L(v_2),..., L(v_k)$} where $L$ is function for linear mapping/ linear transformation.

Comment: What if nullspace of L is non-trivial?

Comment: I have not learned nullspace/kernels yet only a bit of linear mapping and some facts about linear independence

Answer (score 1):

You need additional properties that make sure $L$ has full rank on $\mathrm{span}(v_1,...,v_k)$. For instance take $L=0$ as counter example.

Comment: How would I take L=0 to be a counter example? I am having troubles with starting this..

Comment: If $L=0$ then, whatever $v_1,...,v_k$ are, $L(v_1),...,L(v_k)$ will **not** be linearly independent. Thus the statement does not hold for every $L$ and is disproved. A reformulation of the condition "make sure the rank is full on $span(v_1,..,v_k)$" which I mentioned would be "make sure $L$ be injective on $span(v_1,..,v_k)$".

Comment: Thank you! I read the first sentence and immediately got it :)